# High packet loss and latency bursts on Ubuntu (wifi) but not on macbook testing at the same time?

Tags: networking, wireless

I have a tp link t4uh

https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/download/archer-t4uh/ on Ubuntu 20.04 and Some Airport Extreme with Broadcom firmware on the macbook air.

The network *is* bad unfortunatley but it seems like things are way worse on my ubuntu setup. I am thinking of buying a new adapter just to see but am wondering if there is anything else to debug on the ubuntu side to see why so much packet loss is happening. I think the signal strength is -47 dBm on ubuntu and -57 on the mac device.  What is *very* suspicious is that the noise level is reported 0db on ubuntu and -95 dBm on the mac. (see below for ubuntu iwconfig) output)

```
enx503eaa4de20b  IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"TALKTALK01FBF8"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 40:9B:CD:01:FB:F8   
          Bit Rate:130 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=100/100  Signal level=-45 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```